# Triming the data in excel cell to extract the rss feed url from the source code of the web page

Tags: excel, trim

Hello Everyone,
               I have an excel column where each cell contain a source code of web page. The source code contains an rss feed url of the website. How can I extract the rss feed url from the long html code residing in the cell?

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: I cannot past a whole source code here because of limited text length . You can visit    view-source:http://www.zebra-media.com/ for example.